# Saving UIImage files with NSCoding by converting them to NSData

Tags: iphone, uiimage, nsdata, nscoding

I am trying to save a UIImage fro an `ABRecordRef` in my own `NSCoding` conform Class. As far as i am now i can tell, that `UIImage` is not `NSCoding` conform so i tried the following work-around by using `NSData` instead:

```
- (id)initWithRecordRef:(ABRecordRef)record{
    //Getting the image
    if (ABPersonHasImageData(record)){
        CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(record);
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *) imageData];
        CFRelease(imageData);
    }


    return self;
}

     - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
            //encode NSData representation from UIImage
            tempData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            [aCoder encodeObject:tempData forKey:@"image"];
        }

    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
        //image
        tempData =          [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"image"];
        image=              [UIImage imageWithData:[tempData valueForKey:@"image"]];
        [tempData release];

        return self;
    }
```

for some reason, the programm crashes as soon, as i try to save an instance of this class.
What did i do wrong, or better: how can i accomplish what i want? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be your `[tempData release]` call in the decoder.  As far as I can see, there's no retain count through an allocation, so it's releasing an object that shouldn't be released.  If that doesn't do the trick, I would set up a couple log statements in each method to see which are called before the crash occurs.  This will give us a better idea where to focus

Comment: First of, there was no need for the release, so you where right with that. Unfortunately, this did not slove the Problem.
I tried it some more times and it seemd, the error is in this statement:

`image=              [UIImage imageWithData:[tempData valueForKey:@"image"]];`

as i looked over it, i undersood, that the `valueForKey` part was unnessesary.

This part now works, but now i get the sigarbit if i try tu assign an image from loaded data to an imageview...
does image saveing in NSCoding even work like this? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: It's good you spotted the `valueForKey:` part.  I skipped right over that, unfortunately.  How are you assigning the image to the imageView?  This is purely a guess, but it sounds like the image is being released before you assign it to the imageView.

Comment: first i load a saved instance of my class `RealRecord`, then i assign the image to an `UIImageview` named `avatarView` like this: `-(IBAction)loadSavedContact{
    RealRecord *myRecord = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self saveFilePath]];
    if (myRecord == nil){
        NSLog(@"loading failed");
    }
    avatarView.image=myRecord.image; // SIGARBIT happens here
}` sorry for the unstructured code; didn't know how to make it better in comment.

Comment: No no, that's completely fine.  At this point, it looks like we're going to have to use some logs to get to the root.  First off, does the "loading failed" log ever get triggered?  I only ask because it looks like the code continues regardless, so if there's a nil record, it still tries to assign an image.  Either way, it would be a good idea to put the following logs in right before `avatarView.image=...`.  `NSLog(@"myRecord = %@", myRecord");` `NSLog(@"avatarView = %@", avatarView");` and `NSLog(@"image = %@", myRecord.image");`.  This should help narrow down what's wrong.

Comment: well, the if statement was just a fast try to find out if the loading worked. will add the else statemet. i did add the logs, now it seems clear, te problem is wit the image and not te assignment, because it says:`2011-09-16 17:39:00.736 test2[2883:207] myRecord = <RealRecord: 0x5946790>
2011-09-16 17:39:00.738 test2[2883:207] avatarView = <UIImageView: 0x5936a60; frame = (112 0; 96 124); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x5936b30>>` and i get the SIGARBIT already at the `NSLog(@"image = %@", myRecord.image");` statement.

Comment: Ok good.  I mean, it's not good, but we know where the issue is.  Looks like it's just a matter of assigning the image to your myRecord object.  I'd go back to your original code up top and look at the values that are given before you `return self`.  And make sure that `RealRecord` has a `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;` statement or some thing similar in the header file as well as a `@synthesize image;` in the implementation file